# Segmentation fault when inserting values from file into linked list

Tags: c, input, linked-list, scanf

I want to read values from a text file with has a string int int format like so:

```
testing 5 17
charlie 12 1
delta 88 4
```

I have a function that reads the file using fscanf, puts the input into some variables then send them to a function that inserts them as a linked list node:

```
void readFile(LinkedList *inList, char* file)
    {
    char* tempName;
    int tempLoc, tempNum;

    FILE* f;
    f = fopen(file, "r");
    if(f==NULL) 
        {
        printf("Error: could not open file");
        }
    else
        {
        while (fscanf(f, "%s %d %d", tempName, &tempLoc, &tempNum) != EOF)
            {
            insertFirst (inList, tempName, tempLoc, tempNum);
            }
        }   
    }
```

The insertFirst function:

```
void insertFirst(LinkedList* list, char* inName, int inLoc, int inNumMeth)
    {
    LinkedListNode* newNode;
    newNode = (LinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));
    newNode->className = inName;
    newNode->loc = inLoc;
    newNode->numMethods;
    newNode->next = list->head;
    list->head = newNode;
    }
```

When I traverse the linked list to print out the values, it gives strange symbols for the name (�t) and incorrect numbers for the ints before crashing with a segmentation fault. I'm having trouble tracking down the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `fscanf` call is writing to an uninitialised pointer.  This invokes undefined behaviour and its a little surprising it doesn't crash.

You need to allocate storage for the string

```
char tempName[30];
```

and should also modify your `fscanf` call to read at most this many chars and check that all 3 of name, location, method were read

```
while (fscanf(f, "%29s %d %d", tempName, &tempLoc, &tempNum) == 3)
```

As noted by Marcus, you also need to allocate storage for `className` in `LinkedListNode`.  The easiest way is to make `className` a 30 element `char` array and use `strcpy`

```
strcpy(newNode->className, inName);
```

or you could also leave `className` as a `char*` and dynamically allocate its memory

```
newNode->className = malloc(strlen(inName)+1);
/* check for newNode->className != NULL */
strcpy(newNode->className, inName);
```

If you do this, make sure to free `className` when you free the node.

Comment: and should allocate memory to store the string for each new node.

Comment: Thanks, but why would strcpy be necessary?

Comment: @user2368481 Without the `strcpy` you're just copying the address of a buffer inside `readFile` into the node.  If you create multiple nodes, they'll all point to the same memory.  When your program leaves `readFile`, all nodes created will point to stack which may be reused by other parts of the program or may even become unreadable.  By using `strcpy`, you copy the strings contents, not just its address.

Comment: I understand now, thanks for that. Strings take some getting used to.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* tempName;
```

is not pointed to a memory area. and you have used in the fscanf without assigning it to a memory:

You can fix that by changing the tempname declaration:

```
char tempName[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
```

or you can keep the declaration and use `"%ms"` instead of `"%s"` in the format string specifier in the fscanf

```
fscanf(f, "%ms %d %d", &tempName, &tempLoc, &tempNum)
```

`%ms` will allow to fscanf to allocate memory for tempName. you have to free this memory with `free()` when your memory become useless

Note `%ms` is valid if the gcc version is > `gcc 2.7`

Comment: I hadn't been aware of the `%ms` format specifier - thanks.  Shouldn't you pass `&tempName` to use it though?  Also, the format specifier looks like it might be a non-standard gcc extension.  If this is correct, it'd be important to point this out.

Comment: %ms is valid if the gcc version is > gcc 2.7

Comment: Thanks for making the updates.  My point was more that there are other compilers beyond gcc, e.g. if the o/p is using Windows (s)he is probably using `cl`.  It'd be worth warning that you can only use this approach if you happen to be using gcc and don't care about portability.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to deep copy inName; all you are doing in

```
newNode->className = inName
```

is copying the pointer, not the actual string data. You can use strcpy to do that.

Answer (score 0):

char* tempName;

tempName is pointing to random memory.So allocate the memory for tempName.

Return Value of fscanf :
On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.

Answer (score 0):

Also you should store null in the last linked list as the data reading from the file is finished.